# Jquery not able to set value for slider dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have below slider in my html5 page:

```
<input type="range" name="start-weight" id="start-weight"  value="100" min="100" max="500"  data-mini="true">
```

I'm trying to change its value dynamically using javascript function as below:

```
$('#start-weight').val(400).slider('refresh');
```

The value remains 100 and there is no movement for the slider

Comment: Not clear . what is your problem .SEE : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wV9ea/ . There is no pb

Comment: and your `console` says ...

Comment: console doesnot say anything...... no error

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't jQueryUI slider element need to be a div? http://jsfiddle.net/wV9ea/1/

Comment: no chk out ucan work like this too:
<li class="ui-field-contain">
     <label for="start-weight">Start Weight:</label>
     <input type="range" name="start-weight" id="start-weight"  value="100" min="100" max="500"  data-mini="true">
    </li>

Comment: But you can't convert an input to a jQueryUI slider element, thus making `.slider()` function not work. You must use `<div>` according to http://jqueryui.com/slider/ document

Comment: atleast value should be set

Comment: @user3706255 The value is set look at Abdennour Toumi's comment  http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/wV9ea/

Comment: it is not changing dynamicaly in my case

Comment: @Anton chk out http://mobile-web-app.blogspot.in/2011/11/jquery-mobile-set-value-of-slider-using.html

Comment: @user3706255 .....What is dynamic for you?

Comment: when the page is getting load a javascript function is called within which the above slider is set

Comment: @user3706255 It is getting called.....take a look at this if you want it to be interactive http://jsfiddle.net/wV9ea/2/

Comment: Wrap your code with a DOM-Ready-Handler `$(function(){/*Your code*/});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $('#start-weight').val(400).slider('refresh');
    )
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using? I get an error with the latest... Uncaught Error: no such method 'refresh' for slider widget instance

Comment: jquery 1.10.2 and jquery mobile 1.4.2